# How to show that vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the norm $||x||_1=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ is not strictly convex

Tags: vector-spaces, fourier-analysis, normed-spaces

prove that vector space $\mathbb{C}^n$ with the norm $||x||_1=\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ is not strictly convex

I know I need to show a case where the relation  $||u+v||=||u||+||v||$ $\iff$ u=tv for some  $0 \ge t\in \mathbb{R}$ doesn't hold.

however I can't seem to think on a correct edge case.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: perhaps I am missing the point but those vector are not compilable with the strictly convex relation.
there is no $0 \ge t\in \mathbb{R}$ so that $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = t\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$
and they have different norm so they invalid for both side of the relation thus not invalidate the relation.

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. Quite do not understand the $0 \geq t$ part. But maybe